# How to check whether two arrays have the same parameters in every position, i

Tags: java, arrays, loops, boolean

I'm having trouble with the following problem:

boolean sameStepShape(int[] a, int[] b) that checks whether the two parameter arrays a and b are the same overall shape in that every position i has the same classification (upstep, downstep or plateau) in both arrays. (Your method may assume that a and b have same length.)

```
public boolean sameStepShape(int[] a, int[] b) {
boolean sameStep = true;

for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
    if(a[i] < a[i+1] && b[i] < b[i+1]){
        return sameStep;
    }
    else if(a[i] > a[i+1] && b[i] > b[i+1]) {
        return sameStep;
    }
    else if(a[i] == a[i+1] && b[i] == b[i+1]) {
        return sameStep;
    }        
} 
return sameStep = false;
}
```

However, this code isnt passing the test class and im not too sure why. I'm a little stumped. If anyone can offer any input, it'd be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Apologies, I forgot to include this piece of informtion:

"Based on how the value in some array position i compares to the value in its successor position i + 1, each position i in the array a is classified as an upstep if a[i] < a[i + 1], a downstep if a[i] > a[i + 1], and a plateau if a[i] == a[i + 1]. The last position of the array has no such classification, since there is no successor element that we could compare its value with."

Comment: The problem is not clear, what result do you want to achieve?

Comment: Have you tried tracing through the code either on paper or using a debugger? Do you notice that the loop returns on the first successful match?

Comment: Apologies. I forgot to include this piece of information.

"Based on how the value in some array position i compares to the value in its successor position i + 1, each position i in the array a is classified as an upstep if a[i] < a[i + 1], a downstep if a[i] > a[i + 1], and a plateau if a[i] == a[i + 1]. The last position of the array has no such classification, since there is no successor element that we could compare its value with."

Comment: Based with that information, you need to create the method I posted above. I made sure to implement the information given...just cant figure whats wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out a while ago but I thought I'd post the solution here just for everyone to see.

```
public boolean sameStepShape(int[] a, int[] b) {
boolean sameStep = false;

for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
    if((a[i] < a[i+1]) && (b[i] >= b[i+1])){
        return sameStep;
    }
    else if((a[i] > a[i+1]) && (b[i] <= b[i+1])) {
        return sameStep;
    }
    else if((a[i] == a[i+1] && b[i] != b[i+1])) {
        return sameStep;
    }        
} 
return sameStep = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could break it down into two problems, make a step array to determine if the values went up or down, and then determine if the step arrays are equal:

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
    int[] a1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 8};
    int[] a2 = {1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 7};

    char[] s1 = getStepArray(a1);
    char[] s2 = getStepArray(a2);

    System.out.println(isEqual(s1, s2));
}

public static char[] getStepArray(int[] arr){

    char[] stepArr = new char[arr.length-1];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if(arr[i] < arr[i+1]){
            stepArr[i] = 'd';
        }
        else if(arr[i] > arr[i+1]) {
            stepArr[i] = 'u';
        }
        else if(arr[i] == arr[i+1]) {
            stepArr[i] = 'p';
        }        
    }

    return stepArr;
}

public static boolean isEqual(char[] arr1, char[] arr2){
    for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
        if(arr1[i] != arr2[i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Right now your code isn't working because you are returning true immediately if any values are equal:

```
if(a[i] < a[i+1] && b[i] < b[i+1]){
    return sameStep;
}
```

But you want to do it the other way and return false if any of the values are not equal:

```
if((a[i] < a[i+1]) != (b[i] < b[i+1])){
    return false; //return false here since they are not the same
}
```

Same with the other if statements. Since having only one value be false means the arrays are not equal, but having only one value be true does not mean that the arrays are equal.

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead

```
public sameStepShape(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    if (array1.length != array2.length)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
        if (array1[i] != array2[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It's a check that at each pair of adjacent elements, both arrays have positive, negative or zero differences.

Comment: oh, my bad then. Disregard my answer.